# Can I use np.arange with lists as my inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The relevant excerpt of my code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def create_function(duration, start, stop):
    rates = np.linspace(start, stop, duration*1000)
    return rates

def generate_spikes(duration, start, stop):
    rates = [create_function(duration, start, stop)]
    array = [np.arange(0, (duration*1000), 1)]
    start_value = [np.repeat(start, duration*1000)]
    double_array = [np.add(array,array)]
    times = np.arange(np.add(start_value,array), np.add(start_value,double_array), rates)
    return times/1000.
```

I know this is really inefficient coding (especially the start_value and double_array stuff), but it's all a product of trying to somehow use `arange` with lists as my inputs.

I keep getting this error:

```
Type Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like element, or a number, not 'list'
```

Essentially, an example of what I'm trying to do is this:

I had two arrays `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `b = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`, I'd want to use `np.arange` to generate `[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.3, 3.6, 3.9, 4.4, 4.8, 5.2]`? (I'd be using a different step size for every element in the array.)

Is this even possible? And if so, would I have to flatten my list?

Comment: np.array([i+j for i in a for j in b])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) there for efficiency purposes -

```
(a + (b[:,None] * a)).ravel('F')
```

Sample run -

```
In [52]: a
Out[52]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [53]: b
Out[53]: array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4])

In [54]: (a + (b[:,None] * a)).ravel('F')
Out[54]: 
array([ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3.3,  3.6,  3.9,
        4.2,  4.4,  4.8,  5.2,  5.6])
```

Looking at the expected output, it seems you are using just the first three elements off `b` for the computation. So, to achieve that target, we just slice the first three elements and do that computation, like so -

```
In [55]: (a + (b[:3,None] * a)).ravel('F')
Out[55]: 
array([ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  3.3,  3.6,  3.9,  4.4,  4.8,
        5.2])
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.
I'll have to work towards understanding this, but it does just what I wanted it to. Thank you!